# Python module will not run correctly from command prompt

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, pydev, windows-8.1

This goes out to anyone who is well versed in the Eclipse IDE and or PyDev perspective plug-in who is willing to offer some technical support.

I am trying to write a python module that must take in arguments from the command prompt with sys.argv function calls. Rather than printing out the correct output when I enter E:\ ... \src>program.py arg1 arg2, all that happens is a new command line (E:\ ... \src>) is output and the Eclipse IDE window flashes orange without any code in my python module actually being executed. Also, if I close the Eclipse IDE and try to run program.py, it will just open Eclipse again and open my program in a new tab.

I'm confused as to why it is not working now when just last week it was working perfectly while testing another program that took in arguments from the command prompt by sys.argv function calls. My question for everyone is whether or not you are aware of any settings that may have been altered by updates, etc. that could cause this problem; or has anybody out there ever run into this problem and figured out how to resolve it? I have already checked my PATH variable, so that is not the problem :-(. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated ... thank you.

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro / Eclipse ver.: Kepler (4.3) / Python ver.: 3.3.2

Comment: Since I do not have a reputation of 10 or higher, stackoverflow will not let me answer my own question for another eight hours; I will just have to answer it in a comment then. Turns out that I must have accidentally set all ".py" files to automatically open with Eclipse, not Python Launcher for Windows (console) sometime earlier this week. Once I switched it back, everything worked as it should. Hope this helps someone else out who makes the same silly mistake I did someday.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question in the comment above. I just had to wait to post an answer due to the fact that I just created a stackoverflow account yesterday.